# "Indianata"? Come è venuto ad essere questo termine?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, meaning, etymology

Giovedì scorso, dopo esserci incastrati su un esercizio, la prof ha aperto un libro e abbiamo risolto con un metodo diverso, che coinvolgeva un "trucco", diciamo un escamotage. Nell'enunciarlo, la prof ha detto:

> Ecco l'indianata.

"Indianata"? Ho cercato sul Wikizionario (prima [Inglese](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=indianata&title=Special:Search&go=Go&searchToken=2spewtfcswdv9spta5e7d0gi8) e poi [Italiano](https://it.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=indianata&title=Special:Search&go=Go&searchToken=59ajfqvtkt1a7spno6cjtg7rn)) e sul [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ricerca/indianata/1/) (prime due pagine di risultati), e anche su [etimo.it](http://etimo.it/?term=indianata&find=Cerca), e non ho trovato il termine. Cercando con Google, ho solo trovato [riferimenti a un gioco](https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080716061059AAFPYPa), che sembra non entrarci un fico secco (perdonate il francesismo) col contesto in cui ho sentito la parola. Dunque mi chiedo:

> È una parola che si è inventata lei? Oppure esiste qualche fonte autorevole che la definisce precisamente? L'avete mai sentita questa parola, in questa accezione?

**Update**

Scusate il ritardo ma sono stato molto occupato ultimamente. Un po' più di contesto. Esercizio in questione.

> Sia X uno spazio topologico localmente compatto di Hausdorff. Sia μ una misura su X tale che per ogni Boreliano B di X si abbia μ(B)=1 o μ(B)=0. Allora μ è una delta di DIrac.

L'idea era ordinare l'insieme Y dei compatti di X di misura 1 per inclusione inversa e applicare Zorn. Quindi presa una catena in Y volevamo usare l'intersezione come maggiorante. Essa è compatta perché intersezione di chiusi, quindi chiusa, e contenuta in tanti compatti, quindi compatta. È non vuota perché la catena, totalmente ordinata com'è, ha certo la FIP, da cui l'intersezione di tutti i suoi membri è non vuota. Ma la misura? La continuità dall'alto funziona solo per catene numerabili. La regolarità non ci portava da nessuna parte. E riporto ora un estratto della registrazione della lezione.

> Dunque dunque dunque dunque, ci siamo arrivati a una ìmpass. Eh sì. Eppure credo che, uh dunque, vediamo un attimo, dunque dunque dunque. [Suggerimento poco seguibile di un compagno.] Io mi stavo chiedendo se questa cosa qui… no, adesso mi stavo chiedendo io se, se, mm… che tutti gli spazi che io ho in mente sono spazi che, perlomeno, di solito sono metrizzabili, no? Uuuh, X topologico di Hausdorff localmente compatto, e adesso sto dicendomi, mumént, topologico di Hausdorff localmente compatto, magari chiede anche che sia metrizzabile, questa cosa qui. Ummmm, vado a prendere un libro. OK? Vado vado a dare un'occhiata a un libro, perché qui mi sembra che o siamo impantanati su qualcosa di stupido, oppure…. […] Probabilmente credo che in partenza si può pigliare qualcosa di un pochino più restrittivo, adesso vediamo un attimo eh. […] Allora, un attimo, lui dice… calma eh, adesso, calma calma calma calma un momento. Qui noi siamo in uno spazio topologico di Hausdorff localmente compatto. Perfetto. Adesso, adesso, lui, in realtà, restringe un attimino la cosa, nel senso che dice, OK, abbiamo trovato un sottoinsieme compatto di misura 1. Va bene? Adesso, uuuh, concentriamoci su quell'insieme compatto di misura 1, su K, quindi, uuuh, lasciamo perdere tutto X, ci concentriamo sul K compatto (io), K-segnato che avevo detto all'inizio (io). Perché tanto, se la misura è concentrata su K-segnato, posso pensare che…  il resto (io), ecco, perché tanto il complementare ha misura zero (io), che tutto il restoo, che tutto il resto non, uuuh, non esiste. Quindi quella Γ sono la famiglia degli aperti diii K (io)? Come? O degli aperti di X (io)? Quella Γ lì (io). Γ lì sono gli aperti di K. OK (io). Allora. Tutti gli aperti di K tale che μ(V)=0. OK. [Insomma Γ={V contenuto in K aperto tale che μ(V)=0.] Ecco lì (io). Allora, sì K-segnato (io), questo l'ho chiamato K-segnato (io), per ogni…, OK. Allora, dice, Γ non è vuoto perché, va beh, va beh (io), uummm (io), Γ non è vuoto (io)… perché c'è l'insieme vuoto (io), no la parte positiva (io)…, va beh, l'insieme vuoto appartiene a Γ. Va bene, quindi ∅∈Γ (io), come insieme misurabile, come insieme misurabile. Quindi Γ≠∅ (io). E dice, adesso, sia V l'insieme di tutti…, diciamo, vii, V-corsivo, V-segnato, adesso cancello un attimo qua (io), l'unione di tutti questi aperti. Ha-ha, ecco qui che, mm, ci siamo. Quindi sia il nostro V-corsivo (io)… l'unione di tutti questi aperti, l'unione per V in Γ di V (io). OK. Dice, adesso μ() è zero. Ah (io)! **E qui c'è l'indianata, perché μ() è l'\esup\ delle misure dei compatti, contenuti in , ma un compatto contenuto in  si può coprire con un numero finito di elementi di di di coso.** Ah ecco il trucco (io)! **Ecco l'indianata!** Va bene. Quindi sia K compatto contenuto in , implica esistono V<sub>1</sub> (io), esiste una famiglia di aperti V<sub>1</sub>,…,V<sub>n</sub> (io), che chiaramente la famiglia Γ è un ricoprimento aperto del K (io), eh certo, e quindi c'è un ricoprimento… e quindi ho un sottoricoprimento finito tale che K è contenuto nell'unione dei V<sub>i</sub> (io). Quindi μ(K) sarà minore o uguale della μ(∪V<sub>i</sub>) (io), che è minore o uguale (io), ho qui (io), [ed essendo i $V_i$ in numero finito posso usare la subadditività per concludere μ(∪V<sub>i</sub>)≤∑μ(V<sub>i</sub>),] OK, che chiaramente è zero (io). OK. Cioè, mi sembrava che bisognasse usare tutte e due le regolarità della misura, però siam partiti sbagliati, col piede sbagliato. Quindi abbiamo trov (io), e quindi cos'abbiamo (io)… e quindi abbiamo trovato… che l'unione ha misura zero (io). Uh, abbiam trovato un insieme, uuuh, abbiam trovato… un aperto di misura zeroo massimale di fatto (io), esatto, e quindi vuol dire (io)… allora, il complementare sarà il famoso K<sub>0</sub> che mi serviva (io), esatto, esattamente, cioè un, uuh, un A<sub>0</sub> minimale chiuso, uuuh, quindi compatto, tale che μ(A<sub>0</sub>)=1. OK (io), quindi (io). E quindi esiste K<sub>0</sub> (io), che a questo punto potrò dire che è <sup>C</sup> (io), massimale rispetto a quello che avevo detto prima (io), sì, compatto massimale rispetto alla relazione d'ordine inversa, oppure minimale rispetto alla relazione d'ordineee, allora (io), minimalità (io), che (io), per ogni compatto tale che μ(K)=1 (io), K⊇K<sub>0</sub> (io). Questo è quello che possiamo dire (io). Cioè K contiene (io)… no, minimale, no, minimale, non che K⊇K<sub>0</sub>, K non può esser contenuto in K<sub>0</sub>. K (io)… Allora (io), diciamo (io), K⊆K<sub>0</sub>=>K=K<sub>0</sub> (io). OK.

Quindi l'*indianata* sarebbe il trucco usato di passare al ricoprimento finito per concludere che μ()=0.

Entrambe le volte che lei usa questo termine lo sento piuttosto chiaramente nella registrazione, quindi sono sicuro che non ho sentito male.

**Nota fonetica**

"uuh" (con un numero imprecisato di "u") è uno spelling anglofono, quindi va pronunciato come /ǝǝ/ o /ʌʌ/, non /uu/.

Comment: Per quel che vale, anche io lo avevo presente solo nel senso di gioco/pretesto per bere, e dei vari lessici che ho sott'occhio lo riporta solo il dizionario di termini gergali *Scrostati, gaggio!* di Ambrogio e Casalegno, appunto in questo senso: «Gioco di gruppo in cui chi sbaglia deve a turno, come punizione, bere un alcolico» e menziona anche una canzone di Elio e le Storie tese. Sicuro di aver sentito bene? Se sì, non farà parte semplicemente del “lessico famigliare” dell'insegnante?

Comment: Sembra anche a me una parola del "lessico" dell'insegnante, però, per provare a capire: in cosa consisteva l'escamotage che ha sbloccato la difficoltà?

Comment: Anche io credo che questo termine faccia parte del "lessico famigliare" dell' insegnante. In ogni caso, "indianata" sembra implicare in questo contesto il continuo ricorso ad escamotage a sotterfugi da parte degli indiani, così  come il termine "americanata" si riferisce a comportamenti ritenuti tipici degli americani.

Comment: @Benedetta ed altri, l'update mostra l'escamotage in questione.

Comment: _Indianata_ mi pare accostato a _furbata_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entrambi i termini discendono dallo stesso significato: "qualcosa che fanno gli indiani / tipico degli indiani".

Nel primo caso, il gioco/bevuta, il riferimento è alla tradizione nativo-americana dei [cerchi di discussione](https://teachingfirstnationsstudents.wordpress.com/communication-patterns/). Ai primi del '900 in alcune *fraternity* era diffusa una parodia di questo rituale, in cui i partecipanti sedevano in cerchio e bevevano a turno dopo un brindisi, o dopo aver recitato o inventato un verso di una canzone (adesso, credo, si beve [in maniera meno strutturata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraternities_and_sororities#Alcohol)). Nella variante italiana la bevuta di solito deve farla chi *sbaglia* a recitare il verso o il compito assegnatogli, e le regole per muoversi nel cerchio variano; ma l'origine del gioco rimane evidente.

Nel secondo caso, quello usato qui, ci si riferisce (apparentemente) alla fama dei nativi d'America, di usare abili trucchi quando scendevano in battaglia (fregare il nemico [contava a volte più che ucciderlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_coup)). In alternativa, potrebbe anche essere nato come riferimento al [trucco della corda indiana](http://www.cesnur.org/2005/mi_corda.htm): in questa pagina ho per esempio trovato la parola come "[uscita da indiani, cosa strana](http://www.cornaro.net/124-indianata/)", e [qui](http://www.fuorivia.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=19384&start=30), dal contesto, l'uso è identico.

Comment: Non capisco bene: il nesso con i “trucchi” dei nativi americani è una tua supposizione? E quello con il trucco della corda, che si riferisce invece all'India?

Comment: Necessariamente, si tratta di supposizioni; non sono riuscito a trovare riferimenti autorevoli. E almeno controllando google trends per il periodo recente, il termine sta andando in disuso: https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=indianata

Comment: Grazie per i link. Giusto per chiarire per chi lo usasse poco: i grafici di Google Trends si riferiscono all'andamento delle *ricerche* del termine in questione su Google. Nel nostro caso, probabilmente c'entrerà la canzone di Elio e le Storie tese.